# Apache2 Server configuration with subdomain

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-12.04, subdomain

I have a simple httpd.conf, which is working

```
<VirtualHost *>
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

    DocumentRoot "/opt/rt4/share/html"
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

        SetHandler modperl
        PerlResponseHandler Plack::Handler::Apache2
        PerlSetVar psgi_app /opt/rt4/sbin/rt-server
    </Location>
    <Perl>
        use Plack::Handler::Apache2;
        Plack::Handler::Apache2->preload("/opt/rt4/sbin/rt-server");
    </Perl>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I connect to MyDomain.dynamicDNSServer.TLD, I load my RT just fine.

But since I want it to be rt.MyDomain.dynamicDNSServer.TLD, I set it to exactly the same thing, except I make it

```
<VirtualHost rt.MyDomain.dynamicDNSServer.TLD>
```

and now when I restart Apache2, it says "No address associated with hostname: Could not resolve host name rt.MyDomain.dynamicDNSServer.TLD -- ignoring!"

How would I do that? I cannot assign it a static IP in hosts, since it will change whenever my router grabs a new IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, be sure that you have a *specific subdomain dyndns entry* or a *wildcard  dyndns entry* for your ip. This means that besides `MyDomain.dynamicDNSServer.TLD` also either `*.MyDomain.dynamicDNSServer.TLD` or at least `rt.MyDomain.dynamicDNSServer.TLD` have to resolve to your dynamic ip. If you have neither of these you cannot use a subdomain-specific apache configuration.

In apache, subdomains are specified by `ServerName` and not using the `<VirtualHost>` directive (see [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/de/mod/core.html#servername) for further information).

The following should work for your subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName rt.MyDomain.dynamicDNSServer.TLD
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    DocumentRoot "/opt/rt4/share/html"
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Still does not work, it still behaves the same way. Cannot access it via rt.MyDomain.dynamicDNSServer.TLD. Even with the servername directive in there, I can still access it via MyDomain.dynamicDNSServer.TLD

Comment: @AntonRoth You have to use a specific or wildcard dynamic dns entry (this has to be set up with your dyndns provider). Otherwise you can't use subdomain-specific apache configurations. I updated my answer accordingly.